# How to select pixel with smallest number in stack raster using Python script in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, raster-calculator

I have 6 tiff file in ArcGIS which are identical in term of geometry (same frame, same number of row and column). The pixel value of each tiff file is integer and range from 1 to 4.

So if I overlay them on top of each other, for each pixel I will have 6 DN number (think like an RGB color composite). Now I need an output raster with pixel value that take the smallest number in the stack. So for 2 pixel that have 123456 and 334662 it will take 1 and 2 as output respectively.

I would like to do it in Python but if it can be done via Raster Calculator or ModelBuilder it would also be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use the [Cell Statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000007q000000.htm) tool, you can set which statistic you wish to compute, in your case MINIMUM.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot. Any further suggestion on a python method (for the shake of learning) is still much appreciated.

Comment: anh.hv if some has given a solution to your question you should tick it as answered to let others know and award reputation points.